# Search for an item in a text file using UIMA Ruta

Tags: regex, annotations, nlp, uima, ruta

I have been trying to search for an item which is there in a text file.

The text file is like 
Eg: `

### >HEADING

### 00345

### XYZ

### MethodName : fdsafk

### Date: 23-4-2012

### More text and some part containing instances of XYZ`

So I did a dictionary search for XYZ initially and found the positions, but I want only the 1st **XYZ** and not the rest. There is a property of XYZ that , it will always be between the 5 digit code and the text **MethondName** .

I am unable to do that.

```
WORDLIST ZipList = 'Zipcode.txt';
DECLARE Zip;
Document
Document{-> MARKFAST(Zip, ZipList)};

DECLARE Method;
"MethodName" -> Method;


WORDLIST typelist = 'typelist.txt';
DECLARE type;
Document{-> MARKFAST(type, typelist)};
```

Also how do we use REGEX in UIMA RUTA?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to specify this. Here are some examples (not tested):

```
// just remove the other annotations (assuming type is the one you want)
type{-> UNMARK(type)} ANY{-STARTSWITH(Method)};

// only keep the first one: remove any annotation if there is one somewhere in front of it
// you can also specify this with POSISTION or CURRENTCOUNT, but both are slow
type # @type{-> UNMARK(type)}

// just create a new annotation in between
NUM{REGEXP(".....")} #{-> type} @Method;
```

There are two options to use regex in UIMA Ruta:

- (find) simple regex rules like `"[A-Za-z]+" -> Type;`
- (matches) REGEXP conditions for validating the match of a rule element like
  `ANY{REGEXP("[A-Za-z]+")-> Type};`

Let me know if something is not clear. I will extend the description then.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Hey Peter , thanks for the help. Really Helpful . I had another doubt. Is there an option to pull out or export the output as a CSV or XLS. If there is, can you provide me the code for the same.

Comment: UIMA Ruta does not provide such a component. I normally write a custom analysis engine or cas consumer for this task since the layout is most often project specific. Best ask on the UIMA user list or create a new question here.